# stats twitter api python gives error

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, request

I am trying to get stats via twitter api but I am getting end point error.
I am using https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI

```
stats = api.request('stats/accounts/123456?entity=LINE_ITEM&entity_ids=8u94t&start_time=2017-09-30&end_time=2017-09-30&granularity=TOTAL&placement=ALL_ON_TWITTER&metric_groups=ENGAGEMENT')
statsinfo = stats.json()
pprint(statsinfo)
```

I found the information above via twitter documentation, but not sure why I am getting this error.

raise Exception('Endpoint "%s" unsupported' % endpoint)

Answer (score 0):

The `stats/accounts` endpoint is included in Twitter's Ads API which is not an open API. You must apply for access -- see [doc](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/ads/general/overview).

Currently, [TwitterAPI](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI) does not support the Ads API. It is simple to add this support by updating [TwitterAPI/constants.py](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI/blob/master/TwitterAPI/constants.py) with the missing endpoints. I am the maintainer of this Python package. In the future, I may add the missing endpoints. However, I do not have access to the Ads API myself.